# unable to insert in sqlite database for iphone when app is terminated and started again

Tags: iphone, sqlite, operation

```
-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase{
    NSLog(@"hello");
    databaseName = @"EMAP234.sql";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    NSLog(@"database path %@",databasePath);
    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return;

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
    [fileManager release];
}

-(void)insertIntoDatabase:(NSString *)insertCommand{
    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement = [insertCommand UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;


        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            NSLog(@"inserted");
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {}
        }

        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

the app works fine for the first time but when i restart it , it can read the earlier values but cannot insert new ones ... pls help

here is how I am calling this....

```
DatabaseOperations *obj=[[DatabaseOperations alloc]init];
[obj checkAndCreateDatabase];
NSLog(@"patient ID %d",[obj readMaxPatientIDFromDatabase]);

patientID= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HCI%d", ([obj readMaxPatientIDFromDatabase]+1)];
NSLog(@"patient ID %@",patientID);
[self generatePatientInsertCommand];
[obj insertIntoDatabase:patientInsertCommand];
[self generateCarrierInsertCommand];
[obj insertIntoDatabase:carrierInsertCommand];
[self generateSyncTableInsertCommand];
[obj insertIntoDatabase:syncTableInsertCommand];
NSString *msg=@"your PatientID is";
[obj release];
msg=[msg stringByAppendingString:patientID];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"REGISTERED" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Ankit I used your code and called

```
[self checkAndCreateDatabase];
[self insertIntoDatabase:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO User (uId,userName,userBirthday) VALUES (\"%d\", \"%@\", \"%@\" )",3,@"Admin",@"2010-12-01"]];
```

The only thing I changed is using a different database file which I choose in  checkAndCreateDatabase function by

```
-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase{
    NSLog(@"hello");
    databaseName = @"MasterDB.sqlite";
....
}
```

The code worked fine for every insert with a new uId. Please check your read Function and If Possible then paste the code for read function along with the above code and the way you call these two viz read and insert functions.

Comment: entries are not made in the database , I have checked via sqlite manager. I have these two functions in an nsobject class and call them from a rootViewController.

Comment: You mentioned "the app works fine for the first time but when i restart it , it can read the earlier values but cannot insert new ones". Can you paste the code, the way you call these methods from rootviewController ?

Comment: Resolved the problem by creating the schema while the database was created and not by creating the tables dynamically.